# On Visible Powerapps Gallery items

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I am using below syntax to hide one item only from gallery but it hide all items when i navigate to gallery from input form , it should hide row which have below value but it hide everything unless i do refresh

```
 Visible=  If(Title5_3.Text="Test1",false,true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try defining the visibility of the gallery and the item separately.

Refer to answer by PK_Hong in another post:

1. Define:

   `Gallery1. Visible = CustomGallerySample`
2. The screen which contains Gallery1 as:

   `Screen1. OnVisible = UpdateContext ({CustomGallerySample: true})`

   When you navigate to Screen1, it will force the Gallery to be visible.
3. Use a control to navigate to the screen containing the Gallery.

   `Button. OnSelect = Navigate(Screen1); UpdateContext ({CustomGallerySample: ! CustomGallerySample}).`
4. Add your syntax on Screen1.

Reference:

[Control conditional visibility.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/Control-conditional-visibility/m-p/58224#M24109)